# How to call Android function from phonegap HTML page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-ndk

i make Android application that can communicate to bluetooth printer for printing some text, now i want to call that android function that i made `printText()` from my phonegap html file.. has anyone know how to do that?? thanks.. :)

here's my code:

```
private void printText() {
        EditText EditText1;
        EditText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String temp;
        try {           
            mPrinter.reset();  
            mPrinter.printTaggedText(EditText1.getText().toString());           
            mPrinter.feedPaper(110);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error(R.drawable.text, getString(R.string.failed_print_text) + ". " + 
                    e.getMessage());            
        }
    }
```

and here's my HTML file:

```
 <HTML>
    <BODY>
        <!-- What Should i Do?? -->
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a plugin in order to do this:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android